# How to create an event to drop the table and the other event if no records exists

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am creating a bus table with an event to maintain th data. Is it possible to drop the table and the `autoDelete` event by `DropBusEvent` event if no records exist in the bus table?

```
        stt.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bus"
                + "(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,"
                + "mac VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,"
                + "route int(11) NOT NULL,"
                + "latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
                + "longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,"
                + "created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");

        stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS  AutoDelete "
                + "ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 MINUTE "
                + "DO "
                + "DELETE FROM bus WHERE created_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)");

        // I tried this statement here but it does not work.
        stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXITS DropBusTable "
                + "Do "
                + "DROP TABLES IF EXISTS bus");
```

I am getting `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXITS DropBusTableDROP TABLES IF EXISTS bus' at line 1`

Comment: There is a typo - EXITS should be EXISTS

Comment: @Richard: I am still getting this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXITS DropBusTable Do DROP TABLES IF EXITS bus' at line 1` Futhermore,  the problem I am just setting the event without checking whether records exit  in the table? How can I set the event to check that?

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your syntax:

`EXITS` instead of `EXISTS`
in the line

```
stt.execute("CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXITS DropBusTable "
```